# How to find path of certifcate installed

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-phone-7, winapi

Consider following case, suppose I have register path HKLM\XXX so whenever a new certificate installed there is new key will be added in this path.

I have register a callback on this registry path but is there is any way to figure out from which path the certificate was installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Phone or something else? I see WinForms in the tags.

Comment: Hi Den It's generic question for Win7 or WP7.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this out-of-the-box on Windows Phone 7 due to standard security restrictions. **Do not** confuse Windows and Windows Phone 7, as both sport different security policies that give the developer different levels of access to system components.